# Cannot integrate third party tools with TectCafe Studio

Tags: typescript, testcafe, faker.js, nanoid

I'm new to TestCafe and TypeScript.

I was trying to integrate the NanoID module to TestCafe following [this](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402795/recipes/integrations/import-third-party-modules) tutorial. But it shows an error saying `Cannot find module 'nanoid' or its corresponding type declarations. (2307)`.

But when I tried with uuid, it worked for the following code.

```
var uuid = require("uuid");
var id = uuid.v4();
```

How can I fix this or can you recommend me another module like faker.js? 
(I want to generate random data for testing purposes)

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Comment: I think you mean the auto-generated file in VS Code? I'm sorry I'm using TestCafe Studio for this automation

Comment: Do you see a `node_modules` folder somewhere?

Comment: No sir. It only has ts files which I created. Please refer the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VS87dxkgIApvkj4VC8RZXfG4M0Fv50pZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And how are you running/compiling it?

Comment: That means you haven't installed `nanoid`. You will have to install it.

Comment: is it an IDE or VS Code?

Comment: I have installed nanoid from the command prompt `npm install nanoid`

Comment: I'm using TestCafe Studio. It is an IDE

Comment: If you have done `npm install nanoid`, it must endup somewhere. Usually that's a `node_modules` folder in the project's path.

Comment: So what should I do to enable that installed module in TestCafe Studio?

Comment: There is this [repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples), may be that should help you figure out...

Comment: And a usage, [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/blob/master/examples/import-third-party-modules/index.js)

Comment: I have tried those references before and it didn't work for me sir

Comment: Try this `import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';` import form?

Comment: For that one, I'm getting the error I have mentioned in the question

Comment: It seems there are 2 things... `Visual-Recording Test` and `Script-Based Test`.... Can you try running it as `scripts`... The [TestCafe Studio](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/testcafe/archive/2019/12/24/automated-web-testing-when-to-choose-recording-over-scripting.aspx) is meant for `video-recorded testing` it seems...

Comment: Something that says `codeless automation` and `recorded tests`... What you are trying to do is more suitable for `scripted tests`....

Comment: TestCafe Studio can also use for scripted tests. I was working on it and only stuck in here which is generating random data

Answer (score 1):

Faker would be the best fake data generator. First you need to add the faker library into your testing directory. Then just add a custom script and get any data you need by calling the data.

```js
const { faker } = require('@faker-js/faker');
const first_name = Selector('#first_name');
await t
    .typeText(first_name,faker.name.firstName());
```

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation is incomplete , without showing where the module should stay. https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts#import-third-party-modules

Like they said , "The modules should be installed in the test directory." but if you do this using NPM INSTALL is still not working.
I do not belive that there is a way to add node modules to TestCafe Studio until now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).